# Reading the package.json file of the project using the package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I created a package using react js. I need to configure based on some values in package.json in projects that use the package. I am using webpack for packaging.

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
...
"webpack": "^5.74.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
```

I searched for fs,grecafull-fs and fs-extra packages for this process. But since it is based on node.js, I could not process it.

Is it possible to read the package.json file in the project that uses the package with a function in the package I created?

Comment: Does `require("./package.json")` work?

Comment: or `import myPackageData from './package.json'`

Comment: Could you give more details what kind of configuration do you want to store there?